# .XAP file formed only once?

Tags: silverlight

I am developing some application project in Silverlight using deep zoom.I copy my images under ClientBin/Source .However I notice that the associated .xap file is formed only once? I change the code and re-run but still see that there is no modification in the .xap file.Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Copying files to the ClientBin folder is a modification to the associated web project not to the silverlight project.  The MSBuild code detects that none of the files that make up the content of the XAP file has changed and hence doesn't bother to rebuild something which would turn out have exactly the same as the last build.

Comment: How can I go about changing this?I mean isnt the standard method to just copy the files (images) under ClientBin/Source and then run your program? How to ensure they are part of the project.(For the record I did try to add the files from the project explorer but that doesnt seem to help either)